# JQGrid not show select editable value

Tags: php, jqgrid

I got problem as I new in JQGrid. I have grid with editable select. The selection is working well, but when its not in edit mode it shows nothing. I want it to show based on Database (BBarang Field). Any help ?

```
{name:'ITEM', index:'BBarang', sortable:false, width:80, editable : true, edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl: "bee_ambil_produk.php"},formatter: 'select',editrules: { required: true},},
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer can help others face the same problem. specially they are new in jqgrid like me.
Ive tried to remove ,formatter: 'select' and it works